# Manipulating import data

Tags: import

I want to import field service-repairs into Salesforce as new cases. It should be done automatically overnight (service centers will send their repair data *.csv each evening to a ftp/cloud server)
When automatic importing the data, I want to manipulate the data to correct classic spelling mistakes. For example if they write a category for "Dish washer" or "dish-washer" it should be changed to the correct spelling "dishwasher", so all dishwashers are named the same..

Question is how can this be done. Do I have to do this on workflow rules? If yes, is there any way to have a complete matrix how to rename the many different spelling versions into a correct one?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This was closed by the community for being too broad, typically SFSE questions should be very specific to get a specific answer. Hopefully Peter's answer will give you some ideas to get started though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a requirement, I would suggest investing in an ETL tool, just like you would do for any other data transformation. There are a number of these now such as Informatica, Jitterbit, Mulesoft, and plenty more. But for full ETL and scheduling these will undoubtedly come with a license fee.

You could use scheduled data loader batches using the CLI, but the "check for common mispelling" requirement won't be met there.

In this case I would probably suggest you look at implementing a staging object of some kind (in other words a second object representing "Case" that is only used for data imports with no or very little data validation). You could then take the unvalidated data in that object and transform it and move it into cases using Batch Apex.

For the validity checking, I would probably suggest Apex again, but there may be some simple requirements you can accomplish with Workflow rules.